# xgboost plot importance figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, xgboost

How can I change the figure size of xgboost's plot importance function?

Trying to pass a figsize=(10,20) fails with the exception of unknown attribute.

Comment: I ended up rolling my own based on https://github.com/ViennaKaggle/allstate-claims-severity/blob/master/chris/01_Analysis.ipynb

Answer (score 29):

You can pass an axis in the `ax` argument in `plot_importance()`.  For instance, use this wrapper:

```
def my_plot_importance(booster, figsize, **kwargs): 
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from xgboost import plot_importance
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=figsize)
    return plot_importance(booster=booster, ax=ax, **kwargs)
```

Then use `my_plot_importance()` instead of `plot_importance()`

Answer (score 13):

You can also set the figure size with:

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (14, 7)
plot_importance(booster=booster)
```

Answer (score 2):

Only add `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,50)` to your code

For example:

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
plot_importance(model,max_num_features=100)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,100)
plt.show()
```

Adjust (20,100) to enlarge or reduce image size